# vectorization vs. parallelization in R

Tags: r, vectorization

As a toy example, suppose that we have a function called 'my_func' (the code is below) that takes two parameters 'n' and 'p'. Our function, 'my_func', will generate a random matrix 'x' with 'n' rows and 'p' columns and do something expensive in both runtime and memory usage, such as computing the sum of the singular values of 'x'. (Of course, the function is a one-liner, but I am shooting for readability here.)

```
my_func <- function(n, p) {
  x <- replicate(p, rnorm(n))
  sum(svd(x)$d)
}
```

If we wish to compute 'my_func' for several values of 'n', and for each value of 'n' we have several values of 'p', then vectorizing the function and then applying it the combinations to 'my_func' is straightforward:

```
n <- 10 * seq_len(5)
p <- 100 * seq_len(10)
grid <- expand.grid(n = n, p = p)
my_func <- Vectorize(my_func)
set.seed(42)
do.call(my_func, grid)
[1]   98.61785  195.50822  292.21575  376.79186  468.13570  145.18359
[7]  280.67456  421.03196  557.87138  687.75040  168.42994  340.42452
[13]  509.65528  683.69883  851.29063  199.08474  400.25584  595.18311
[19]  784.21508  982.34591  220.73215  448.23698  669.02622  895.34184
[25] 1105.48817  242.52422  487.56694  735.67588  976.93840 1203.25949
```

Notice that each call to 'my_func' can be painfully slow for large 'n' and 'p' (try n = 1000 and p = 2000 for starters).

Now, in my actual application with a similarly constructed function, the number of rows in 'grid' is much larger than given here. Hence, I am trying to understand vectorizing in R a little better.

First question: In the above example, are the calls to 'my_func' performed sequentially so that the the memory usage in one call is garbage collected before the next call? I use vectorization often but have never stopped to ask this question.

Second question: (This question may depend on the first) Assuming that the number of calls is large enough and that 'my_func' is slow enough, is parallelization warranted here? I am presuming yes. My **real** question is: is parallelization warranted here if instead 'my_func' had the same large matrix passed to it for each call? For sake of argument, assume the matrix is called 'y', has 1000 rows and 5000 columns and is calculated on-the-fly. Of course, passing the matrix 'y' to each of the parallel nodes will incur some lag.

I understand that the answer to the second question may be "It depends on..." If that is the case, please let me know, and I will try to give more detail.

Also, I appreciate any advice, feedback, or OMFG WTF N00B YOU HAVEN'T SEEN THIS OTHER OBSCURE SOMEWHAT RELEVANT DISCUSSION??!!!111oneone1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the first question is pretty clearly yes: *almost everything* in R is by default serial. (A very few things internally start to use OpenMP, but R as an engine will likely remain single-threaded).

So for the second question: Yes, do try that.  I don't use `Vectorize()` much, but I do like the `*apply()` family.  Solve it with `lapply()`, then load the [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/package=multicore) package and use `mclapply()` to run it over as many cores as yo u have.  Here is an example:

```
R> system.time(res <- lapply(1:nrow(grid), 
+                            function(i) my_func(grid[i,1],grid[i,2])))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.470   0.000   0.459 
R> system.time(res <- mclapply(1:nrow(grid), 
+                              function(i) my_func(grid[i,1], grid[i,2])))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.610   0.140   0.135 
R>
```

Notice how elapsed time is now about 29% (= 0.135/0.459) of the original.

From here you can generalize further with parallel execution across several machines--the Task View on [High-Performane Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) has further pointers.  R 2.14.0 due October 31 will have a new package 'parallel' which combines parts of [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/package=multicore) and [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been using foreach in parallel via Rmpi with up to 512 cores and with via multicore on a 8-core box. Although it provides an easy interface to parallel computing and allows me to write once for the different configurations across different machines, not knowing what's happening under the hood is causing some headaches.

Comment: I use the *apply() family frequently, so I'll check out mclapply. Any thoughts on a cluster of multiple machines each with 8 cores? Also, does snow (or even snowfall) make it easy to write code once and then port to another configuration by changing the backend? Looks like I have some playing to do.

Comment: Dirk - Will package 'parallel' in R 2.14.0 be supported on Windows? (please say yes, please say yes =)

Comment: "Yes, but ..." it can't overcome certain windows limitations, so multicore is still icky. Prof Ripley added a fair amount of documentation where you find more details.